# Liferay hibernate.cfg.xml location in a portlet made in Liferay IDE

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, liferay, liferay-ide

I'm trying to convert this portlet https://github.com/tlipski/newsletter-for-liferay which was made to compile with maven, to a Liferay Project (then I can work with it in the Liferay IDE). Everything seems to work fine but I don't know where should I put the hibernate.cfg.xml file in the Liferay Project to make it work. At the moment I have it in the WEB-INF/classes folder and I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
at pl.net.bluesoft.rnd.newsletter.model.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:28)
at pl.net.bluesoft.rnd.newsletter.portlets.VaadinApplicationPortlet2.handleRequest(VaadinApplicationPortlet2.java:23)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationPortlet.doDispatch(AbstractApplicationPortlet.java:728)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:101)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:92)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:638)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:723)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:425)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the hibernate.cfg.xml file in the root of your src/ folder.  Then edit the liferay-plugin-package.properties file and go to the portal dependency jars.  Add the hibernate3.jar to your project.  Then it should work on deployment.